# Apache 2.4 from WAMP stopped working as a service after Windows 7 update (possibly)

Tags: windows, apache-http-server, wamp

I had WAMP server installed on my Win 7 computer. After recent update and reboot Apache stopped working. The wampapache service was not started, when I tried to start it manually from services tool, it showed msvcr100.dll error:

```
Faulting application path: D:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.4\bin\httpd.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\MSVCR100.dll
```

I searched thru wamp forums, they said to install windows c++ Redistributable Packagewith needed dlls. OK I installed them, rebooted, reinstalled wamp, rebooted, installed and reinstalled again, rebooted (for 2 days, so I did it many times)

Nothing happens - msvcr100.dll is present in *c:\Windows\System32* directory, its size is 755 KB (773 968 bytes). When I start the service I receive in log the same error.

What can possibly be done in this case? I can install and reinstall anything, I just need the server working.

If some more logs are needed, ask, for I don't know what to attach.

**Update:**

Windows 7 ultimate

MSVCR100.dll:

```
Version language : English (United States)
      CompanyName   : Microsoft Corporation
      FileDescription   : Microsoft® C Runtime Library
      FileVersion   : 10.00.40219.325
      InternalName  : msvcr100_clr0400.dll
      LegalCopyright    : © Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
      OriginalFilename  : msvcr100_clr0400.dll
      ProductName   : Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2010
      ProductVersion    : 10.00.40219.325
```

Comment: Is Windows 32-bit? What's the current version of the `MSVCR100.dll` file?

Comment: I've updated the question

Comment: When was last time things were working properly? Have you got any restore points? Was the [KB2565063](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2565063) update installed recently?

Comment: 2 weeks ago all worked fine (it's a home machine and I seldom use it for dev, so don't sure when all became corrupted, and meanwhile my kids were installed some games). I don't sure regarding restore points, never used them.  I did not install KB2565063 as I have no real VC++ installed on my home computer, only free windows Redistributable Packages with dlls.

Comment: Just to be sure, open a command prompt and execute this command: `wmic qfe | findstr /i /c:"KB2565063"` Then post the output here.

Comment: The output is `No Instance(s) Available`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14008/discussion-between-and31415-and-user15)

Comment: I've done everything (and managed to run scannow,seems that my antivirus was blocking it) All OK, except wamp server. I finally gave up, and installed free version of zend server. Surprisingly, its 32bit apache started to work as a service without problem, so I transferred everything on new server and continued with it. Thank you for you help!!!